# How can find a specific value in a JSON out of other objects with the same name in java?

Tags: java, json

Sorry for the ambiguous question, but I'm new to playing around with JSON and didn't know how else to word it. So say I call an API and it returns lunches:

```
{
   "today's lunch": {
      "options": [
         "choice 1":{
            "main": Burger
            "side": Fries 
         }
         "choice 2":{
            "main": Spaghetti
            "side": Bread
         }
      ]
   }
   "tomorrow's lunch": {
      "options": [
         "choice 1":{
            "main": Sandwich
            "side": Chips 
         }
         "choice 2":{
            "main": Meatloaf
            "side": Bread
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to write a method to get the value of today's lunch -> choice 1 -> main (or any specific value for that matter). Is there a way I can do that? So far, after playing around with Jackson and recursive algorithms, I've only been able to find a way to get the value of all objects named "main", but I really only want the value of the one. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Choose the library that is easy to use with your usecases and go from there. Good place to start is e.g. this comaprison with examples for the most popular choices: https://itsallbinary.com/jackson-vs-gson-vs-json-b-vs-json-p-vs-org-json-vs-jsonpath-java-json-libraries-features-comparison/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.